# Use a variable in another project

Tags: java, android

I have a project named: "temp" which I implement some classes and their methods.

Then I created another project called: "temp2" and I included the library "temp" in order to use the classes that I implemented there.

Now if I created a class in "temp" project:

```
private SwipeListView swipeListView;   // SwipeListView  is a class declared in "temp2" project
private MyCustomAdapter adapter;   // class MyCustomAdapter is a class in "temp" project


swipeListView = (SwipeListView) findViewById(R.id.example_lv_list);
adapter =new MyCustomAdapter(text,listImages);  

swipeListView.setListenerAdaper(adapter);

adapter.someMethod();   //doesnt give me a nullpointerException
```

In the class `SwipeListView` I declared the method `setListenerAdaper(BaseAdpter)` and `useAdapter()`:

```
private BaseAdapter listAdapter;

public void setListenerAdaper(BaseAdapter baseAdapter) {
    listAdapter = baseAdapter;
}

public void tempmethod() {
    useAdapter();
}

public void useAdapter() {
   listAdapter.someMethod();  //NullPointerException
}
```

I want to use the `listAdapter` variable in the class `SwipeListView`, however whenever I want to call a method of adapter in the `SwipeListView`, I get a `NullPonterException`

Comment: are you initializing your swipeListView? I can't see anything like `SwipeListView swipeListView = new SwipeListView();` ?

Comment: yes, of course, i edited my code above

Comment: Make sure you're importing the right `R` (otherwise there will be no view named `R.id.example_lv_list`). Eclipse usually automatically imports `android.R`, which usually is not what you want.

Comment: check which value is `null` and posting some more code will help us more to find the problem.

Comment: yes or course, if i remove the line listAdapter.someMethod();  everything works well...

Comment: from the logCat the nullpointer is the listAdapter variable

Comment: check listAdapter for null before you pass it to `setListenerAdapter()` and also maybe check inside of `setListenerAdapter()` too. Based on your code it is also possible that something inside of `someMethod()` is causing null pointer.

Comment: i edited my code, as you can see if i call someMethod() in the class that i declared in the firstProject "temp" it doesnt give me a nullPointerexception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If variables are on other classes :

1. import other classes
2. and put them on the class path

How to set classpath :

Click on Project --> Properties --> Java Build Path --> (Here You can use either "Add JARs" or "Add External JARs") depending upon the physical location of your JAR files in your system.

Comment: hi, i already imported SwipeListView class, however i didnt understand the second tip :"put them on the class path" can you explain it to me? thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you need to import something from other project I think you need to consider a better architecture.

To achieve that you need to create a jar of the other project, make that variable a class and public one, and finally import it from the class you want to use it.

But as I mentioned before, you need to check your architecture in order to have a library with all the classes that will be used by several projects.